# Npm script doesn't run a script that includes glob pattern

Tags: npm, jscodeshift

### What I have

I'm using `jscodeshift` library to modify some files, so I run it in `npm script` like so:

```sh
"scripts": {
    "build-types": "jscodeshift -t scripts/fixImportPaths.ts src/gql/**/gqlTypes/* --parser=tsx",
  }
}
```

but the console output thrown `No files selected, nothing to do.`, the thing is, if I put the absolute path `src/gql/specificFolder/gqlTypes/specificFile.specificExtension` the script works.

### What I tried

1. Wrap the path with single quotes:

```sh
"scripts": {
    "build-types": "jscodeshift -t scripts/fixImportPaths.ts 'src/gql/**/gqlTypes/*' --parser=tsx",
  }
}
```

2. Wrap the path with escaped double quotes:

```sh
"scripts": {
    "build-types": "jscodeshift -t scripts/fixImportPaths.ts \"src/gql/**/gqlTypes/*\" --parser=tsx",
  }
}
```

#### Environment

- windows 10
- npm 7.7.3

Comment: I'd guess that script expects *files*, not a glob pattern, and Windows doesn't support all the glob syntax so it isn't expanded by your shell.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you know any solution?, because I don't see the viability of placing all the file names

Comment: A quick Google suggests https://www.npmjs.com/package/globstar might help